# Can angular momentum be affected by internal forces in a rigid body system?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, computational-physics, rigid-body-dynamics

This question is motivated by my interest in understanding the angular momentum and energy of a figure skater doing a stationary spin where they move their limbs away from and towards their body to vary the angular velocity of their spin.  I set out to test this in my 2d physics engine using two identical cylindrical rigid bodies, aligned on their axial axes, and connected by a prismatic joint which allows relative motion only along their shared axial axis.  This would be similar to having one cylinder be slightly smaller than the other and sliding it inside the larger one.  The bodies start out spinning around their centroid at a constant angular velocity (being 2d, this would be about the z-axis).  Then a force is applied to each body in the direction of the centroid, effectively compressing the pair.

I expected this to yield constant angular momentum and I wanted to observe what happened to the energy.  However, instead I saw the angular momentum change.  If the bodies only experience a constant inward force to maintain their current separation (so that they act as one rigid body where those forces are then internal forces) or if no force is applied but they start with a constant velocity towards each other, the angular momentum does stay constant.  Can anyone explain why this is happening, or even tell me that is in fact wrong and angular momentum *should* be conserved?

I also verified this behavior with the [Box2D](http://box2d.org/) physics engine.  Although I know it's a game-oriented engine, I am hoping that the consistent results will be helpful.  I have included some graphs taken from the demo program I have, using both engines.  The inflection point around 1.3 seconds in each graph is when the bodies are at exactly the same point and begin to expand rather than compress (since I don't reverse the force direction at all).  Also, if there's any other data I can collect from the simulation that might be helpful, let me know.  Thanks!

[image: angular velocity]
[image: angular momentum]
[image: bar distance from centroid]

**EDIT:** I suppose I should also ask if this is indeed wrong, does anyone know of a computational physics engine that *does* handle this case correctly?

Comment: No, internal forces cannot change angular momentum. It should be conserved. Assuming that the software is not faulty, your programming of it must be at fault. How do you know that the engine is not applying external forces to make the masses move radially?

Comment: The configuration is not clear. You describe 2 identical rigid cylinders. Then one is smaller. You use 2 dimensions, yet they can move wrt each other in z direction (what's the purpose of that motion anyway?). How can you change their radii if they're rigid? You apply a force, but from where?

Comment: @TomB. The 2 cylinders are identical; I used the example of one slightly smaller pipe to help visual the prismatic joint.  They are not moving wrt each other in the z-axis, they are rotating about the z-axis.  They move wrt each other along their axial axis.  If you imagine (in 2d) two line segments drawn on the x-axis, then these are the cylinders and they can move along the x-axis.  After they have rotated 90 degrees they can move relative to each other along the y-axis.  Their radii are not changing; I'm not sure to which statement you're referring.  The forces are at their centroids.

Comment: That clears it up. It sounds like the condition where they have a velocity toward each other accomplishes what you want. The engine must be supplying the appropriate force automatically.